# Biber/Biblatex mismatch after fresh installation of texlive

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, ubuntu, texlive-2023

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and I needed some more updated latex packages, so I manually installed texlive 2023 (after uninstalling the apt-get version, at least so I thought). I correctly set that up in TexStudio (I set under build, as Commands path /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/).

Unfortunately, now `biblatex` and `biber` are incompatible:

> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.10, expected version 3.7.
> This means that your biber (2.14) and biblatex (3.19) versions are incompatible.

However, in the command line, I seem to have a different version of biber:

```
(base) $ which biber
/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/biber
(base) $ biber -v
biber version: 2.19
```

Is Texstudio running the wrong biber executable? The command for biber is `biber %`

Comment: Can you use the full path to biber in your texstudio preferences? `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/biber %`

Comment: probably you set the path in  shell used by your commandline, but started the editor from a desktop shell at a higher level

Comment: If you installed TeXStudio using apt and did nothing to stop it, it is unlikely you removed apt-installed TeX Live as the package for the editor almost certainly depends on TeX Live packages from your distro. There are ways to avoid this, but you have to actively enable them.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu for details.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That fixed the issue. It's odd since I didn't have to do this for any other of the commands.

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/biber Biber is packaged as `biber` in Ubuntu 20.04. So maybe that package was missed when you uninstalled TeX Live (for which most packages are called `texlive-...`). If you still had the Biber binary left over and TeXstudio was configured to give its path preference this might explain it ended up running the wrong binary. It's probably a good idea to tell `apt` to remove the `biber` package as well.